# Move Cell Value to Another Cell in Same Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a simple Google Script, I'm trying to get working but I can't seem to understand my error.

The function wants to move text that is not bold, from one section of the spreadsheet to another after it finds an empty cell.

I've verified I can get values,if the values are weighted bold or not bold, and the location of the empty cell, but when I try to move the text I get this error message:

> TypeError: Cannot find function copyTo in object AS.

I know my error is from this line:

```
matchedCell.getValue().copyTo((emptyCellLocation,1,1,1),{contentsOnly:true});
```

Suggestions?

```
function moveLowerValues() {

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Set values for position of cells to examine  

  var upperRowStart = 1;
  var columnStart = 1;

  var upperRange = s.getRange(upperRowStart, columnStart, 10);

  var upperValues = upperRange.getValues(); // Get all data in one call
  var emptyCellLocation = 1;

  while (upperValues[emptyCellLocation][0] != "" ) {
    emptyCellLocation++;
  } 

  var lowerRowStart = 11;  
  var lowerRange = s.getRange(lowerRowStart, columnStart, 10);

  var lowerValues = lowerRange.getValues();

  var lowerWeight = lowerRange.getFontWeights();

  // Move and clear cells which are not bold

  for (var rowStartOffset=0; rowStartOffset < lowerValues.length; rowStartOffset++) {

    // If the value of the cell does not equal bold, move and then delete it

    if (lowerWeight[rowStartOffset].toString() != "bold") {

      var matchedRow = lowerRowStart + rowStartOffset;
      var matchedCell = s.getRange(matchedRow, columnStart, 1, 1);
      matchedCell.getValue().copyTo((emptyCellLocation,1,1,1),{contentsOnly:true});
      // emptyCellLocation++
      // matchedCell.clear();

    }
  }

  // lowerRange.sort(1);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matchedCell.getValue()` returns the value in that cell: a number, a string, or such thing. This value doesn't have a method `copyTo`. This method is something that a Range object has. Use `matchedCell.copyTo` instead.

Furthermore, the first argument of copyTo must also be an object of Range class. Writing `(emptyCellLocation,1,1,1)` doesn't create such an object. Use the `getRange` method.

Comment: This was my mistake. Thanks!